# Woocommerce update product quantity & price from a service

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Need some advise. I have a xml service which returns Product name / stock price / stock available. I want to update my woocommerce product price & quantity from this service on a regular basis.
How do I go about it ? I believe I need to create a php program where I call this service and then setup a cron job to schedule this program.
is this the right approach ?

which woocommerce function I should call once I have received product price etc from service ?

also my XML service is in below format, how do i format it ?

```
<pricelist>
<row>
<itemid>
<![CDATA[ PRD-0010 ]]>
</itemid>
<class>
<![CDATA[ Asus ]]>
</class>
<subclass>
<![CDATA[ Asus Accessories ]]>
</subclass>
<product>
<![CDATA[ Asus ]]>
</product>
<desc>
<![CDATA[ Asus TX300CA AC Adaptor ]]>
</desc>
<price>
<![CDATA[ 899.00 ]]>
</price>
<stock>
<![CDATA[ low-level ]]>
</stock>
</row>
</pricelist>
```

thanks

Comment: PHP on a cron job is how I'd do it. Using this job to update the database, you shouldn't need to call any woocommerce functions. Just be sure to update all the correct areas.

Comment: you mean direct update of table which contains post ?